# Why is this C code returning unexpected values?

Tags: c, cs50, luhn

I want to multiply every other digit by 2, starting with the number’s second-to-last digit, and then add those products’ digits together, but the first printed values seem completely nonsensical.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int len(long li);

int main(void)
{
    // Get credit card number
    long credit_card = 378282246310005;

    // Adding every second digit's double's digits, starting with the second to last
    int sum = 0;
    int digit_doubled;
    for (int i = 0; i < len(credit_card); i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        digit_doubled = (int) (credit_card / pow(10, i)) % 10 * 2;
        printf("Digit doubled %i: %i\n", i, digit_doubled);
        for (int j = 0; j < len(digit_doubled); j++)
        {
            sum += (int) (digit_doubled / pow(10, j)) % 10;
        }
    }
}

int len(long li)
{
    if (li == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return floor(log10(li)) + 1;
}
```

I have tried modifying the expression to see what results I'd get. When I deleted the
`% 10 * 2` from the end of `digit_doubled = (int) (credit_card / pow(10, i)) % 10 * 2;`, I got results that indicate some kind of integer overflow, but I have absolutely no idea where it could be coming from since my program isn't really producing any high values anywhere.

Comment: When asking for debugging help, including a [mre]. `u` is undeclared in the function `len`, so this code will not compile. It looks like `long li` should be `long u`, as if this code is the result of applying OCR to text. `378282246310005` is likely too big for `long` in your C implementation. Do not use integer types for credit cards; treat them as strings of characters (characters that are digits). Avoid using `pow` (because some `pow` implementations are inadequate) or other floating-point for integer arithmetic; write your own integer routine or design the code not to need exponentiation.

Comment: Trivial simplification: `2*5 + 2*3 + 2*7` == `2 * (5 + 3 + 7)`... Don't make life difficult for yourself.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, sorry about the parameter's name. It was a last-minute edit, and it wasn't like that in my actual code.
I have tried printing the "credit_card" variable after initializing it, and it seems that no information is being lost.
I have to use a long int due to my courses instructions.
Why shouldn't you use `pow` for integer powers, and what is an integer routine?

Comment: @Fe2O3, if the result of the multiplication is over 10, I must add the two digits of the result as well, so that doesn't work.

Comment: Ah! so you really only want `if( x >= 10 )` instead of the internal `loop`. Again, why make it hard? `2 * 3 = 6` so no "folding"... `2 * 8 = 16` so you want `1+6=7` as the value, it seems...  Invoking a loop and `pow()` seems like overkill for such a simple and restricted computation... KISS... Doubling each single digit value `0-9` results in a single digit value... Try a simple "look up table", instead, perhaps...

Comment: @Alan: Some implementations of `pow` return numbers such as 99.9999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375 for `pow(10, 2)` or similar cases, and then converting to an integer yields 99, not 100. An “integer routine” is a routine with integer parameters and an integer return type that performs integer arithmetic.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I am a beginner at C. Could you explain how those routines would work?

Comment: @Alan Make sure accept the best answer by clicking the check mark so we know you are all set.

Comment: It's a lot easier to process the digits in a CCN (credit-card number) if you treat it as a string rather than a number.  You already have the digits separated for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first loop when `i=1` you cast a value greater than the maximum value that can be stored in an integer (2147483647) which cause it to be truncated and on my system go negative:

```
digit_doubled = (int) (credit_card / pow(10, i)) % 10 * 2; // =>
digit_doubled = (int) 37828224631000 % 10 * 2; / =>
digit_doubled = -1847312168 % 10 * 2; // =>
digit_doubled = -16;
```

I suggest you include `stdint.h` and use `uint64_t` instead of silently assume that a long is 64 bit.  Alternatively, consider using a string as a credit number is an identifier not a number (even though it is written as one).

Mixing functions that operate on double for integer type values will open you up to floating point rounding errors.  You could use `uint64_t` versions of these functions instead of `double`.  Below I implemented a `len()` and `my_pow10()` functions for you.  As the value of `digit_doubled` is at most 18 you can just inline that calculation instead of using a loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t my_pow10(uint64_t x) {
    if(x == 0) return 1;
    size_t v = 10;
    for(size_t i = 1; i < x; i++, v *= 10);
    return v;
}

size_t len(uint64_t v) {
    size_t i = 0;
    for(; v; i++, v /= 10);
    return i;
}

int main(void) {
    const uint64_t credit_card = 378282246310005;
    const uint8_t credit_card_len = len(credit_card);
    uint8_t sum = 0;
    for (uint8_t i = 1; i < credit_card_len; i += 2) {
        uint8_t digit_doubled = credit_card / my_pow10(i) % 10 * 2;
        printf("Digit doubled %hhu: %hhu\n", i, digit_doubled);
        sum += digit_doubled / 10 + digit_doubled % 10;
    }
    printf("sum = %u\n", sum);
}
```

Comment: Ugh why is credit_card not a string? This offends my sensibilities.

Comment: @Joshua Because op choose it, however, I think you should make a stronger argument.  Like it's an identifier not a number.

Comment: I am very nooby at C. I don't understand what you mean here. Could you simply tell me what makes my code return completely nonsensical values?

Comment: @Alan I expanded the explanation.  Did that help?

Comment: @AllanWind Casting to `(int)` before doing `% 10` is one of the major problems; another is using `pow`

Comment: @M.M. I agree.  What would you like me to clarify?

Comment: Sorry that was meant to tag OP

Answer (score 2):

Having suggested using a LUT to deliver the single digit value required by the OP's question, here is a snippet of code to do just that:

```
unsigned long long copy = longValue; // perhaps correct on OP's compiler??

copy /= 10; // dispose of the checksum digit (rightmost)

// The following line depends on the OP's problem statement
// Is this digit odd (checksum digit being digit zero)
// or is this digit even? (checksum digit being disregarded.)
// Incl-/excl- next line to suit problem statement.
copy /= 10; // dispose of the rightmost "odd" digit

while( copy ) {
    int digit = copy % 10; // get "even" digit from the right end.

    // Crafted LUT to return correctly "doubled & folded" value of this digit.
    sum += "0246813579"[digit] - '0';

    copy /= 100; // "shift" value down by 100 (ie: 2 digits of value)
}
```

I leave it as an exercise for the OP to determine what characterises "even" and "odd" in the sequence of digits of a credit card "number". Does one count the checksum digit as '1' or not? For the OP to work out...

For fun, here's the loop after compaction.

```
for( /**/; copy; copy /= 100 )
    sum += "0246813579"[ copy % 10 ] - '0';
```

And, a more advanced version would simply calculate the desired value from the supplied value:

```
for( /**/; copy; copy /= 100 )
    sum += copy%5 * 2 + copy%10/5;
```

For those who (reasonably) question the validity of the formula above:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {
    for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
        int j = 2 * i;

        printf( "Digit Value: %d ", i );
        printf( " x2 = %02d ", j );
        printf( "==> %d + %d ", j/10, j%10 );
        printf( "==> %d ", j/10 + j%10 );

        printf( "==== %d\n", i%5 * 2 + i%10/5 ); // <== Formula version
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
Digit Value: 0  x2 = 00 ==> 0 + 0 ==> 0 ==== 0
Digit Value: 1  x2 = 02 ==> 0 + 2 ==> 2 ==== 2
Digit Value: 2  x2 = 04 ==> 0 + 4 ==> 4 ==== 4
Digit Value: 3  x2 = 06 ==> 0 + 6 ==> 6 ==== 6
Digit Value: 4  x2 = 08 ==> 0 + 8 ==> 8 ==== 8
Digit Value: 5  x2 = 10 ==> 1 + 0 ==> 1 ==== 1
Digit Value: 6  x2 = 12 ==> 1 + 2 ==> 3 ==== 3
Digit Value: 7  x2 = 14 ==> 1 + 4 ==> 5 ==== 5
Digit Value: 8  x2 = 16 ==> 1 + 6 ==> 7 ==== 7
Digit Value: 9  x2 = 18 ==> 1 + 8 ==> 9 ==== 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need floating-point arithmetic at all here, or logs or pows. You can use `% 10` to extract the next digit, and `/ 10` to discard it. Like this:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    uint64_t credit_card = 378282246310005ULL;

    int sum = 0;
    while (credit_card != 0)
    {
        credit_card /= 10; // Discard rightmost digit
        int double_digit = 2 * (credit_card % 10);
        credit_card /= 10;
        sum += double_digit % 10;
        double_digit /= 10;
        sum += double_digit % 10;
    }
    printf ("%d\n", sum);
}
```